# Spring Boot - @ConfigurationProperties with nested properties of unknown name

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, yaml, mapping

I have a website with microservice architecture. I want one of my services to be able to check if all the others are up. To do so, I configure for all my services there 'up-check' url, their name, if the check is enabled, and maybe a version.
For instance I have three services : foo, bar, baz, the configuration would be as follow (other properties are ommited)

```yaml
api:
    foo:
        up-check:
            url: ${foo.baseUrl}/up
            enabled: true
            version: ${foo.version}
    bar:
        up-check:
            url: ${bar.baseUrl}/up
            enabled: true
            version: ${bar.version}
    baz:
        up-check:
            url: ${baz.baseUrl}/up
            enabled: true
            version: ${baz.version}
```

On spring side I know want to map these properties to an object as follow (getters, setters and constructors are ommited):

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "api")
public class UpProperties {

    private Map<String, ApiProperty> api;

    public static class ApiProperty {
        private HealthCheck upCheck;
    }

    public static class HealthCheck {
        private boolean enabled;
        private String version;
        private String url;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to be able my `UpProperties` to map any new service I would plug in the property file without changing anything, so I don't want the name of the api to be hardcoded (no `foo`, no `bar` and no `baz`)

> *Edit: I don't know if it's clear enough, but I want my `api` map to be as follow*
>
> ```
> foo: ApiProperty(url, enabled, version)
> bar: ApiProperty(url, enabled, version)
> baz: ApiProperty(url, enabled, version)
> ```

But no matter what I try to change, the map `api` won't be populated, what did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`api` key is your map, not the root class. Try this
Application.yml

```
up-properties:
  api:
    foo:
      up-check:
        url: ${foo.baseUrl}/up
        enabled: true
        version: ${foo.version}
    bar:
      up-check:
        url: ${bar.baseUrl}/up
        enabled: true
        version: ${bar.version}
    baz:
      up-check:
        url: ${baz.baseUrl}/up
        enabled: true
        version: ${baz.version}
```

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "up-properties")
public class UpProperties {

    private Map<String, ApiProperty> api;

    public static class ApiProperty {
        private HealthCheck upCheck;
    }

    public static class HealthCheck {
        private boolean enabled;
        private String version;
        private String url;
    }
}
```